# Pages won't load when article is in shopping list

Tags: cart, session

After adding an article to my shopping list, pages won't load anymore. Look for an example on: http://bit.ly/1cvXGKa

E.g.: Add an article from this page (http://bit.ly/HlmNAZ) by hovering it and clicking on 'In winkelwagen'.

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Please uncomment or add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on your index.php to view any errors in the PHP

Comment: Sander, I already did this (I uncommented the line), but still: no errors...

Comment: By-the-way: I see the URL's (when hovering) behind the menu-items say '______SID=U' at the end. Does this have something to do with my sessions?

Comment: Check out this link as it gives a solution: http://www.richardcarterconsultancy.com/2012/06/removing-session-id-___sidu-from-your-magento-store-url/

Comment: Thanks for that. The SID=U is now hidden, but this doesn't solve my problem; page still does not load. And there is no error. It just seems like the page code suddenly 'stops'

Comment: If there's no error printed or in the apache logs please update your question with the name of the template you are using and the contents of the file `[active package]/[active template]checkout\cart\item\default.phtml`. My best guess is that the problem is in there as the minicart dies when you try to retrieve the first item in the cart. (you can see this in the course of your page)

Comment: Thanks, template name is 'Petsyshop'. You can download the code at http://5.157.82.118/elly/default.phtml.zip

Comment: My mistake, that code is not used in the small cart, please check what PHTML file is by turning on the template hints in the backend. I've checked the demo page for the original template and yours fails on getting the product image in the small cart. Please post the code in your question that is responsible for that. I've tried to start a chat session here but you don't have enough points unfortunately.

Comment: Sander, thanks. That must be this code: 5.157.82.118/elly/topcart.phtml.zip
Btw, check your Facebook chat (folder 'Overige')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some debugging and remembering the previous question of the user (curl not installed) we installed the GD library on the server.

The error existed in the cart where the thumbnail was resized because Magento crashed on the fact that it didn't have an image editing library